# How to do GM_xmlhttpRequest to an url that change its host everytime to cross-domain w/ JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, greasemonkey

I'm creating a simple userscript to Greasemonkey and I want to select an node that is inside of an `iframe document`. The node that I want to select is an `<embed>` that is in an `iframe document` hosted in other domain.

My JavaScript lines (I set `@include` for both domains):

```js
// @include    https://apps*.facebook.com/game/*
// @include    https://integrated-plugin-canvas-*-*.fbsbx.com/apps/*/?params=*
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_canvas');
var otherdocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var unity = otherdocument.querySelector("embed[type='application/vnd.unity']");
unity.style.setProperty("margin", "0px", "important");
```

The url on other domain is `https://integrated-plugin-canvas-1234-5678.fbsbx.com/apps/1234/?params=ABCD` and change its `5678` to other random number everytime, and `ABCD` too. The problem that with `GM_xmlhttpRequest` or `XmlHttpRequest`, one can't set `*` as wildcard (or that I think)... There is some method?

I'm very amateur in JavaScript, I need help. Thanks.

Comment: where is the event code on which you will select this iframe...

Comment: cross-domain communication using iframes isn't possible unless both the target and src domains are setup to communicate through post messages, however even then post messages only transmit text, not dom elements.

Comment: That should only affect the parent doc.

Comment: @Kevin B But if I wrote this:

`document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"`

for example, select and put the style argument to the main body and iframe's body.

Why? And with "Customize Your Web" Add-on for Firefox I can select and edit the iframe document w/o problem, only need include the url of the domain, like I do with @include on Greasemonkey...

Comment: @Kevin B No, because with `@include` I add the 2 urls (main and iframe) therefore when I call document, it apply to 2 domains at the same time, but I don't get call to `<embed>` node in the iframe document :/